# Rails check_box_tag how to pass value when checked ajaxily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On my index page for my Task model, I want to show a checkbox for every row that corresponds to the boolean field "complete" in my Task database table.

Currently my code gets into the method "Complete", but it does not contain the value of the checkbox that the user just did (i.e. if they just checked the box, it does not pass true to my "Complete" method).

How can i pass the value that the user just performed - either checked or un checked?

/views/tasks/index.html.erb

```
<% @tasks.each_with_index do |task, i| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag 'Complete', task.complete, task.complete, :data => {:remote => true, :url => url_for( :action => 'complete', :id => task.id, :complete => task.complete ), :method => :put}, :class => 'input-large' %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

/controllers/tasks_controller#complete

```
# PUT /complete/1
  def complete
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    p "inside complete"
    p "complete = #{params[:complete]}"
    @task.complete = 

      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        p "inside update"
        render :text => "success" 
      else
        p "inside error"
      end

  end
```

Comment: You will have to write a onclick event or onchange event to send a Ajax call. We can't send ajax call on check_box_tag similar to link_to.

Comment: Please. Can you provide a little example how it looks in your view file and js code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can write a click event.

```
$('.input-large').click(function() {
  var checked; 
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checked = true;
  } else {
    checked = false;
  } 
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/tasks/complete",
      data: { id: $(this).data('post-id'), checked: checked }
   });     
});
```

Comment: Rather than have 2 ajax functions, isn't there a way to send the response to the server (checked or unchecked)?

Comment: Ok i tried your solution, but i get the error: "couldn't find task without an id". How can i pass the id?

Comment: There was no data-post-id on my checkbox element so i just changed my check_box_tag to have the id as the id of my task and then added this to my ajax data: `id: $(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 9):

The suggestion from this issue in rails/jquery-ujs github repo worked for me: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/440#issuecomment-197029277

For you it would be:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'complete', '1', task.complete, {
  onchange: "$(this).data('params', 'complete=' + this.checked)",
  data: { url: url_for(action: 'complete', id: task.id,), remote: true, method: :patch },
} %>
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Rails 4, you should be able to ditch all the JS from the original answer. The code in your question should just work due to jQuery UJS magic.

It turns out that adding `remote: true` to an input causes jquery-ujs to make it ajax-y in all the nice ways. Thoughtbot's ["A Tour of Rails jQuery UJS"](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs#ajax-forms) briefly touches this (and many other good things available); the ["Unobtrusive scripting support for jQuery" page](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery) in the jQuery UJS wiki does a thorough job on this as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
check_box_tag 'complete', task.complete ? 'false' : 'true', task.complete, ...
:url => url_for( :action => 'complete', :id => task.id )
```

This way in your controller you can get params[:complete].
And you should implement complete.js.erb to rerender checkbox, so next click will send inverse value

Or you can implement js on click event

```
$('.input-large').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/tasks/complete/" + $(this).data('post-id')
    data: { complete: $(this).is(':checked') }
  });
});
```

and don't forget to place data-post-id param to your checkbox

Comment: If i go with your first option, it doesn't submit ajaxily. If i add `:remote => true` to your first option, it submits ajaxily, but `params[:complete]` does not contain the correct value that the user just did (checked or unchecked), it only contains the value that's in the db.

Comment: In your second example, i had to change the url to `$(this).data('url')` because there was no data-post-id on the generated checkbox element. The ajax call works, but it still does not contain the value that the user just did (checked or unchecked), but just keeps displaying the value that's in the db.

Comment: in first example I put ... to omit duplicates, I reproduced it in my env and it works

Comment: In second I wrote "and don't forget to place data-post-id param to your checkbox"

Comment: I seemed to have overlooked the piece about adding a data-post-id param. That makes sense though.