# Rails + ajax, my "edit.js.erb" is not being run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup ajax within rails, but I am having trouble getting my "edit.js.erb" to be ran

My edit.html.haml

```
= f.check_box :foo, {checked: eligibility_data.foo, class: "foo", remote: true}
```

controller

```
def edit
  @survey = Foo.find_by_id(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

edit.js.erb

```
alert("Testing");
```

How can I get edit.js.erb to run?  Once it's working I want to append html to my view, will I be able to place that html right into my js.erb, or will I have to make a partial of some sort?

Comment: `remote: true` is for links and form submissions. check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697000/rails-check-box-tag-how-to-pass-value-when-checked-ajaxily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append `remote: true` to a checkbox and expect it to fire off.

It needs to either be attached to the parent form tag of said checkbox, or you need to write some js that watches that checkbox.

If you go the watcher route, the JS will send an ajax call when the box gets clicked on.

[Here is a link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on how to do AJAX with jQuery (which is built into rails)

Comment: Thanks, I now have this code in my js `$.get("/foo_data/" + id + "/edit", function(data) {
  })`  This is also hitting my edit method, but the "edit.js.erb" is still not being rendered.

Comment: hmmm...are you sure the edit method is getting called? If so, it should return and fire off that alert. Can you post the server log of it firing off?