# Archiving entries with checkbox and haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, haml

I have a controller where users entries are saved and can be updated by admin. There is an index page which shows the saved and existing entries, a show page which shows the individual entry and an edit page where the entry can be updated. What i am trying to do now is on the index page. I want the entries here to each have a checkbox where the admin can select which ones of these to 'archive'. For now as it is merely just a case of archiving these entries in the sense of being able to clear up the index view i do not want to have a separate archive controller etc but do this within my diagnostics controller as a way to clear up the index view as i have said and nothing needs to be further done with the archived entries at this stage anyway. I followed the rails cast on checkboxes and lists but this did not work for me and i got a "Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound" error. Therefore i have this code still in my view and controller but at this point i have commented it out. I went along the lines of creating a custom route but i think this may have ben where my problems came from as this did not seem to work. I am also trying to use TDD and Capybara for this. If anyone can suggest what i should be doing next it would be much appreciated. I can get the checkboxes and save button to appear but from the controller point of view and the routes i seem to have hit a wall here!

**index**

```
%h1 Diagnostics

%table
  %tr
    %th
    %th User
    %th Message
    %th Device
    %th RELS-Mobile Version
    %th Submitted
    %th Archive
  - @diagnostics.each do |diagnostic|
    %tr
      %td
        %strong= link_to 'show', admin_diagnostic_path(diagnostic)
      %td
        - if diagnostic.user
          = link_to diagnostic.user.email, [:admin, diagnostic.user]
        - else
          unknown
      %td
        = diagnostic.data["message"]
      %td
        %pre= JSON.pretty_generate(diagnostic.data["device"])
      %td
        = diagnostic.data["appVersion"]
      %td
        = diagnostic.updated_at
      %td 
        = check_box_tag 'A Checkbox', method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }

/ = form_tag '/admin/diagnostics/:id/complete', :method => :put do
/   = field_set_tag do
/     = check_box_tag :diagnostic_id, 'diagnostic_ids[]', method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
/     = submit_tag 'Mark as Complete'

= submit_tag 'Save', method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
= paginate @diagnostics
```

**Controller**

```
class Admin::DiagnosticsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_filter :diagnostic, :except => [:index]

  def index
    @diagnostics = DiagnosticInfo.all.order_by(:created_at.desc).page(params[:page]).per(50)
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @diagnostic }
    end
  end

  def update
    if @diagnostic.update_attributes(params[:diagnostic_info])
      redirect_to admin_diagnostic_path, notice: 'Successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    diagnostic.destroy
    redirect_to admin_diagnostics_path
  end

  # def complete
  #  DiagnosticInfo.update_all(["Archive=?", Time.now], :id => params[:diagnostic_ids])
  #  params[:diagnostic_ids]
  #  # redirect_to admin_diagnostics_path
  # end

  private

  def diagnostic
    @diagnostic = DiagnosticInfo.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes**(relevant part)

```
resources :diagnostics 
#   member do
#     put 'complete'
#   end
# end
```

**features/spec (relevant part)**

```
  it "can archive a diagnostic report" do 
    diagnostic_info = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
    visit admin_diagnostics_path
    page.should have_content("test message")
    # save_and_open_page-launchy
    click_button "Save"
    check('A Checkbox')
  end
```

**Model**

```
class DiagnosticInfo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :data, type: Hash
  field :user_id, type: Integer
  field :notes, type: String
  validates :data, presence: true
  #archived @

  index created_at: 1

  def user
    @user ||= User.where(auth_system_user_id: self.user_id).first
  end
end
```

Comment: what i understand that after clicking `save`, you want users to `complete( Archive)` which are checked on index page. Is that true ?

Comment: yes that is the correct. A user is admin though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697000/rails-check-box-tag-how-to-pass-value-when-checked-ajaxily) solution. you can try that, and post if you want any different from it.

Comment: Thanks i had seen this before i posted and as i am not using jQuery although the logic is somewhat similar i was not able to find it helpful. My problem is arising from getting the routes to work and link the code from the view to the controller etc.